# Limiting the number of decimals in a dataframe (R)

Tags: r, decimal, limit, maxlength

I would like to limit the number of decimals when a data frame is imported. My `.txt` input has 16 decimals in each row for the column `Value`. My dataframe look like this:

```
Value 

0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
0.202021561664556
...
```

My expected dataframe

```
Value
0.20202156
0.20202156
0.20202156
0.20202156
...
```

Real input (DF) that does not work:

```
DF <- "NE001358.Log.R.Ratio
    -0.0970369274475688
    0.131893549586039
    0.0629266495860389
    0.299559132381831
    -0.0128804337656807
    0.0639743960526874
    0.0271669351886552
    0.322395363972391
    0.179591292893632"

DF <- read.table(text=DF, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here `is.num` is `TRUE` for numeric columns and `FALSE` otherwise.  We then apply `round` to the numeric columns:

```
is.num <- sapply(DF, is.numeric)
DF[is.num] <- lapply(DF[is.num], round, 8)
```

If what you meant was not that you need to change the data frame but just that you want to display the data frame to 8 digits then it's just:

```
print(DF, digits = 8)
```

In dplyr 1.0.0 and later one can use `across` within `mutate` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(., 8)))
```

Comment: That modification is enough?

Comment: Now, you code works... I really do not understand why it do not works in my real data

Comment: Can I limit the characters in a line in some other way?

Comment: formatC, prettyNum and sprintf are functions for converting numbers to formatted character strings.

Comment: I found a non numeric value in DF... That´s is the cause maybe. If I wanna to maintain those strings and do something about decimals what can I do? Thank you very much!

Comment: `as.numeric` will convert a string to numeric.

Comment: Why do you use sapply() once and lapply() next. Why not use sapply again instead of lapply? It works either way. Any particular reason for using lapply if desired output is data frame?

Comment: Because `is.num` is a numeric vector and DF is a data.frame (which is a list).

Comment: Recently getting this suggestion in version `1.0.7`,
ℹ `..1 = across(is.numeric, ~round(., 3))`.

ℹ Predicate functions must be wrapped in `where()`.
Seems like new change

Comment: Thanks. have udpated.

Answer (score 22):

A `dplyr` solution using [`mutate_if`](https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-2/#mutate-if) to check if the columns in the current data frame are `numeric` then apply the `round()` function to them

```r
# install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 8)
#>   NE001358.Log.R.Ratio
#> 1          -0.09703693
#> 2           0.13189355
#> 3           0.06292665
#> 4           0.29955913
#> 5          -0.01288043
#> 6           0.06397440
#> 7           0.02716694
#> 8           0.32239536
#> 9           0.17959129

### dplyr v1.0.0+
DF %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ round(., digits = 8)))
#>   NE001358.Log.R.Ratio
#> 1            -0.097037
#> 2             0.131894
#> 3             0.062927
#> 4             0.299559
#> 5            -0.012880
#> 6             0.063974
#> 7             0.027167
#> 8             0.322395
#> 9             0.179591
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I have a dataframe of 13 columns where the 1st 2 columns are integers and the rest of the columns are numeric with decimals. I want the decimal values alone to be restricted to 2 decimal places. Applying @G. Grothendieck 's method above, a simple solution below:

`DF[, 3:13] <- round(DF[, 3:13], digits = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

just throw a copy of this into the path of your project in a utils
directory and source it when you run your script

```
"formatColumns" <-
 function(data, digits)
 {
    "%,%" <- function(x,y)paste(x,y,sep="")
    nms <- names(data)
    nc <- ncol(data)
    nd <- length(digits)
    if(nc!=nd) 
      stop("Argument 'digits' must be vector of length " %,% 
           nc %,% ", the number of columns in 'data'.")
    out <- as.data.frame(sapply(1:nc, 
                         FUN=function(x, d, Y)
                         format(Y[,x], digits=d[x]), Y=tbl, d=digits))
    if(!is.null(nms)) names(out) <- nms
    out
}
```

Now you can sit back and relax

```
formatColumns(MyData, digits=c(0,2,4,4,4,0,0))
```

et cetera et cetera et cetera