# How to round the unnecessary numbers (0.0000 seconds) in the time format?

Tags: r

I got the speed at 3.17m/s and need to convert to the pace "mn'ss.000/1km".

I start with `as.numeric(3.17*86400)/1000`，then add  `hms(as.numeric(3.17*86400)/1000)`, turns out to be `04'33.970286`. How to just leave the result as `4'33.970`?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217520/limiting-the-number-of-decimals-in-a-dataframe-r) < might be able to answer your question. The answer there might be worth a try.

As stated in the link:

> Here `is.num` is `TRUE` for numeric columns and `FALSE` otherwise. We then apply `round` to the numeric columns:

> `is.num <- sapply(DF, is.numeric)`
> `DF[is.num] <- lapply(DF[is.num], round, 8)`

> If what you meant was not that you need to change the data frame but just that you want to display the data frame to 8 digits then it's just:

> `print(DF, digits = 8)`

> In dplyr 1.0.0 and later one can use across within mutate like this:

> `library(dplyr)`
> `DF %>% mutate(across(is.numeric, ~ round(., 8)))`

thanks to @G.Grothendieck

Comment: Please consider summarizing the information in the link in words/code. As it stands this could be considered link only NAA.